# Is it wrong for OP to incorporate suggested changes into their posted code?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I saw the following comment on an SO question posted by a user with 10K+ reputation and addressed at OP:

> Don't ever edit questions to fix errors in the posted code. All
>   comments and answers are instantly turned into nonsense. This is very
>   bad form for SO.

I'm talking strictly about cases when the change is made by OP him/her-self.

Where does community stand on this issue?

Does it matter whether a suggestions that OP implemented by editing the question was given to her/him in a form of a comment or an answer?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well... Either you misread or I was not clear.  I edited it a bit.

Comment: I've posted that comment many times myself and rolled back the edit. I obviously don't know the context here, but if the the edit is considerable enough to change the question, then it's a bad idea. If they have a new question, they should ask it in a new question. In this case, based on your last paragraph, it sounds like the OP wanted to copy the solution into their question, but overwrote the problem. That's no good. It hides the original intent and renders the answers pointless.

Comment: The only case where this would be the right course of action is where the OP has posted a shortened version of their real code to reproduce the issue and has made a mistake in the provided example that doesn't allow the actual issue to be reproduced. If they effectively edit their post to answer their question, then no, it shouldn't be edited.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the change.

#### Chameleon Questions

There are cases where someone posts an answer to a "real problem" (i.e. a problem that is not something banal like a typo) which the OP incorporates into the question. Most of the time when I see this, it is accompanied with a note that says "I did what @soandso recommended but now I have this problem...". **In cases like this, the question should be rolled back** and a note similar to the one cited in this meta question could be left for the OP. It is not impossible I've sometimes left a comment like the one cited in the question here but often what I do is point out that the OP is turning their question into a "chameleon question", and that the new issue should be posted as a different question.

#### Posting the Solution in The Question

Someone posts a comment that provides the solution. The OP edits the question to incorporate the solution. **This should be rolled back because solutions should not be in questions.** They should be in answers. When I run into this, I roll back and leave a comment that the OP should invite whoever commented to post their comment as an answer or that the OP should post the answer.

#### Typos and Similar Things

Every now and then someone is going to post an answer that points out an issue in the question that is just an artifact of posting on SO. For instance the OP introduced a typo when posting the question, or the OP tried to simplify their code as they typed it into the question field and changed a variable name or a path but forgot to change it somewhere else, etc. Someone posts an answer that fixes this mistake. **In situations like these the question should be edited to fix the issue and the answer should be deleted.** There's no value in keeping the solution to these kinds of mistakes for posterity.

Comment: In the third case, it probably should not have been posted as an answer in the first place, as that's what comments are for.

Comment: @Deduplicator True, although sometimes a user may think that they have found the real problem the OP is having, only to later find out that it was *a* problem, but not the cause of the problem described in the question.

Comment: It was case #2, though the suggestion took care only of a part of OP's problem.