# Should I rollback the OP's edits, if they just replicate my answer's proposed changes?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I have answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633122/vector-v-s-infinite-loop/29633410#29633410) (poorly titled ***"vector v.s infinite loop"***), and the OP incorporated the proposed solution into their question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29633122/4). This made the answer a bit of useless, because the originally posted codes problems were addressed there.

While it looks to me the original problem is solved (actually check and manipulate the `std::istream` state as needed), the original code better fit's for Q&A format. Also the title is pretty poor, to describe origin of the problem.

I'd appreciate proposals, how to improve the question for future research, with respect to the accepted answer.

The title should be something like ***"Why does this code end up in an infinite loop, reading from std::cin"*** IMHO (better proposals appreciated).

---

I could have used brute force<sup>1</sup>, rolling back to the original post, and editing afterwards (included giving the question a better title), but I'm not so sure, that's why I'm asking.

I have read **["Is it wrong for OP to incorporate suggested changes into their posted code?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285653/is-it-wrong-for-op-to-incorporate-suggested-changes-into-their-posted-code)**, but I'm asking from the editor's point of view.

---

<sub>1) I have used *brute force* to edit the question meanwhile.</sub>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it wrong for OP to incorporate suggested changes into their posted code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285653/is-it-wrong-for-op-to-incorporate-suggested-changes-into-their-posted-code)

Comment: @gnat Well, I'm asking from an editor's POV.

Comment: as far as I can tell, dupe covers the current title of your question. "Should I rollback the OP's edits, if they just replicate my answer's proposed changes?" - in the case of chameleon questions, rollback is the right thing to do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say that in these situations there are two main possibilities:

1. The OP copies part of your code, using it to *improve* theirs, but the problem still does exist and didn't change adding/editing the code.
2. The OP copies your code and edits the question using it to actually *solve* the problem: now the visible code hasn't got errors/lacks anymore, and the post loses its original meaning.

#### What should you do?

1. In this situation there's really nothing wrong: the OP just wanted to improve the rest of their code, and you provided him with a useful snippet, so, although it may be questionable, **there's nothing wrong with editing the original code, given that it maintains the original problem even after the edit is applied**. Maybe it would be a good practice to add some kind of note/comment like "note: improved my code thanks to `<answerer>`".
2. In this second scenario, you should take some action, because now the post lost its previous meaning (for the sake of a Q&A site). **If the OP edits their question in this way, then there's no more question: rollback the edit** (maybe improve the post) and kindly warn the OP about why he shouldn't do that.

---

To answer your question:

> I could have used brute force, rolling back to the original post, and editing afterwards (included giving the question a better title), but I'm not so sure, that's why I'm asking.

**Yes, in this case you should rollback the edit.**

Comment: There seemingly has been some intermediate state with the copied code in a non working form. All at all the OP missed to be clear about their actual problems from the beginning (and with the title).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, I see that the OP's intention is not very clear (at least at the first sight). I also got confused and had to read it twice.

Comment: I could have used brute force, rolling back to the original post, and editing afterwards (included giving the question a better title), but I'm not so sure, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I edited my answer

Comment: You meant _your answer_ (not question).  And confirmed by your suggestion I edited the post in question as well ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ whops, sorry, yes! All right then :)